# expected dense_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)
```

When I run:

```
num_classes = 2
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[64,64,1]))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding ='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=5, padding='same'))

model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
#model.summary()

#Compile and train the model
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x = tr_img, y = tr_lbl, epochs=2, batch_size = 5)
```

My input (image) data is stored in a numpy array, and has shape:  (300, 64, 64, 1)

My labels have shape: (300, 2) and are in one hot format like so: [0,1]...

How do i solve this?

Comment: Doesn't `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` require categories encoded as integers, and not hot encoded?

Comment: Use `categorical_crossentropy` for your _loss_ function. `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is used when your target is **Integer**, and NOT **one-hot-encoded**.

Comment: In `keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[64,64,1]` your _input_shape_ should be [tuple](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/InputLayer) `(64,64,1)`, and not a **list**.

Comment: @RezaBehzadpour you can use a list if you want.. doesn't have to be a tuple

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your loss function. You should be using `loss='binary_crossentropy'` or `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` if you are using a softmax ouput with one-hot-encoded labels